# Why is the debugger saying the code is different when setting breakpoint?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I have one asp.net mvc project with one wcf ajax service on it.

I successfully created a simple operation that returns a generic list of strings.

I successfully consume that in my asp.net mvc view using ajax through jquery.

the issue is I can't debug using breakpoints inside the operation service.

The only way I can make it hit is by right click the break point, choose "locations" and set "Allow the source code to be different from the original version"

but why is the code different in the first place?

am I cursed to always do this in order to use breakpoints in ajax based wcf services inside asp.net mvc applications?

thanks

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class FightService2
{
    // To use HTTP GET, add [WebGet] attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
    // To create an operation that returns XML,
    //     add [WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Xml)],
    //     and include the following line in the operation body:
    //         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml";
    [OperationContract]
    public List<string> DoWork()
    {
        List<string> l1 = new List<string>();
        l1.Add("something_a");
        l1.Add("something_b");
        l1.Add("something_c");
        return l1;
    }

    // Add more operations here and mark them with [OperationContract]
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/FightService2.svc/dowork",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                data: "",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    alert("e3: " + msg.d.length + " - " + msg.d[0]);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Try: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General Tab -> Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"